# How to use indexing to replace a row of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I would like to substitute a one-row vector for some of the rows of a matrix in R.  Here is an example.
I would like to substitute the row "5,6" for the rows in A where the entries are 1.  So, I would like to make "A" look like "A_goal"

The method I attempted (see the bottom line) was close, but it seems that it's writing "down the columns" instead of across the rows.

```
A=matrix(c(1,2,1,3,1,2,1,3),4,2)
B=matrix(c(5,6),1,2)
A_goal = matrix(c(5,2,5,3,6,2,6,3),4,2)
A
B
A_goal

# Here is an attempt that didn't work:
A[A==1]=B
A
```

Answer (score 1):

Matrix indexing using `{<-` is done with column major ordering. So you will probably need to use apply on a row basis. This is essentially a for-loop over the rows of A. You also will need to transpose since apply will also deliver the results as columns:

```
 t(apply(A, 1, function(x) if(x[1]==1){B}else{x}))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    6
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    5    6
[4,]    3    3
```

If you were only intending the replacement to occur where the row was c(1,1) then the logical test would need to be modified to x == c(1,1)